# How to stop dummy customer registrations in Magento 1.9.3.3?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, email, filter, registration

Need To Stop Dummy email address registration.

Comment: what you mean by dummy email or customer?

Comment: You can enable a Magento Captcha for a register form in System > Configuration > Customers > Customer Cunfiguration > Captcha

Comment: I have verified my Magento admin panel and set as "Require Emails Confirmation = Yes" but, still i'm getting fake registrations, I think need to change customer folder / file permissions like readable only but, I'm not sure where and how to change the privileges. And also In customer configuration there is no "magento catpcha" provision in my admin panel I have configured Google re-captcha but, still receiving the same. Any suggestions??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Magento has the feature to verify the authenticity of newly registered customers before activating their account.

You can set confirmation setting to avoid Fake entries:-

```
**– Go to System -> Configuration -> CUSTOMERS -> Customer** Configuration
**– Click => Create New Account Options
– Set Require Emails Confirmation => Yes
– Save Config**
```

Now, whenever a user register to your Magento shop, he/she will get a confirmation email with a confirmation link. The customer’s account will be activated only after he/she clicks that link.

**Enable CAPTCHA:**

The first line of defence CAPTCHA. This adds a challenge for automated bots to be able to enter a random value as displayed in the image on the page. To enable the CAPTCHA, navigate to the following path in the Magento `Admin (Admin > System > Configuration > Customers > Customers Configuration > CAPTCHA)`. CAPTCHA can be enabled on,

```
Customer account registration
Customer Login
Forgot Password
Customer account registration during checkout
Checkout as guest
```

Comment: Already we set "Require Emails Confirmation = Yes", but still added.

Comment: i suggest you add captcha on the registration page and add powerful validation on customer registration page,

Comment: i just edit my answer on captcha, check it @AshishKacha